# Python CSV file is not being read as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a piece of code that is supposed to extract data from a csv file, which is made up of two columns of numbers. The code looks like

```
from csv import reader

CMdata = reader(open('CMdata.csv', 'rU'))

BrSquared = []
for column in CMdata:
    BrSquared.append(column[0])

print BrSquared
```

This is producing a list. I expected it to read the first column and print the values, which would be

```
['2000, 2000, 3000,...,4950],
```

but it reads the whole file, producing a list like

```
['2000\t\t0.00000002068', '2000\t\t0.00000002068',..., '4950\t\t0.00000004754'].
```

Why is this? How can I produce a list like the one I want?

Comment: That's a tab-delimited file. By default, `csv.reader` looks for commas. Try `reader(open('CMdata.csv', 'rU', delimiter='\t'))`.

Comment: if you show a sample of the CMdata.csv that will make things easier. But it seems like your file is delimited with new line as well as there is a tab between the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your csv is using a `\t` as a separator

try:

```
CMdata = reader(open('CMdata.csv', 'rU'), delimiter="\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your file has some tab delimited data as well as the column that you want to parse is the first column. Please check if the following code helps you.

```
CMdata = reader(open('CMdata.csv', 'rU'))
[x[0].split("\t")[0] for x in CMdata]
```